# Why should be accept this ${\displaystyle {n \choose k}}=0 $ for $k> n$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, factorial, convention

I'm confused how  ${\displaystyle {n \choose k}}=0 $  for $k> n$ however the 
ratio :${\displaystyle\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}}$ is not defined for $k>n$ ?

**My question here is:** Why should be accept this $${\displaystyle {n \choose k}}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}=0 ,  for , k> n$$ ?

**Note:** I don't accept this if it were by convention because it's not defined !!!!

Thank you for any help

Comment: You could instead define $\binom{n}{k}$ to mean "the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set". Then the formula with factorials would not be the definition, but a consequence of the definition. This way it makes sense, because there are no subsets bigger than the set itself!

Comment: Because the binomial coefficients are not defined as that quotient but as something else which does equal $0$ in these cases (take your pick of the number of ways to choose $k$ out of $n$ elements, or the coefficient in the binomial expansion).

Comment: Because $\binom{n}{k}$ has the usual interpretation of "number of ways to choose $k$ objects in a set of $n$ objects". In how many ways would you choose $n+j$ elements in a set of $n$ elements?

Comment: ok, i meant that by it's definition with factorial ratio

Comment: That you don't accept this is somewhat irrelevant, really. This convention is widely used and is in fact quite natural —as it has combinatorial and analytical justifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s the natural interpretation when $\binom{n}k$ is given its combinatorial interpretation as the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set. Moreover, outside very elementary treatments the binomial coefficient isn’t actually defined as

$$\binom{n}k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\;;$$

a common and much more general definition is

$$\binom{x}k=\frac{x^{\underline k}}{k!}\;,$$

where $x^{\underline k}=x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-k+1)=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-i)$. This definition is actually valid for all real $x$ and all non-negative integers $k$, and when $n$ is a non-negative integer less than $k$ we have $n^{\underline k}=0$, since one of the factors is $n-n$.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible definitions of $\dbinom nk$ is that it's the coefficient of $x^k$ when you expand $(1+x)^n$ as the product of $n$ factors (whence the name of *binomial coefficient*).

Now in this expansion you have no $x^k$  term  if $k>n$ or if $k<0$.

Note the formula $\;\dbinom nk=\dfrac{n!}{k!\,(n-k)!}$ is only a *theorem*, valid for $0\le k\le n$.